# Implement condition in for..in loop

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

I am looking at **for..in** tutorial from MDN documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

The example iterates over the object's properties and prints all. I am trying to print only if value of object's property is 3. Can someone please help me understand where I am going wrong. And also if possible explain.

```
const object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

for (const property in object.c == 3) {
  console.log(`${property}: ${object[property]}`);
}
```

Comment: You need to put the condition inside the loop, your current code is the same as saying `for (const property in true) {...` (because `(object.c == 3)` evaluates to `true` in this case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for...in` loops can't have conditions.¹ You have to implement the condition as an `if` within the loop:

```
for (const property in object) {
    if (object[property] === 3) {
        console.log(`${property}: ${object[property]}`);
    }
}
```

I've assumed you want *any* property with the value `3`, not just `c` (since there'd be no need for a loop).

---

¹ *"`for...in` loops can't have conditions"* So why didn't you get an error? Because your code was syntactically correct, it just didn't do what you expected.

The `for (const property in object.c == 3)` is evaluated like this:

1. Calculate the result of `object.c == 3`. Now we have:

   ```
   for (const property in true) // or `in false`
   ```
2. Since `for...in` only works on objects, convert the boolean primitive to a Boolean object. Now we have:

   ```
   for (const property in new Boolean(true)) // or `in new Boolean(false)`
   ```
3. Since `Boolean` objects have no enumerable properties, the loop never does anything.

Comment: A pleasing footnote.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do every task step by step. The for in loop is for iteration. After that, you use an if conditional to check if the property is equals to 3. Check the code below:

```
const object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

for (const property in object) {
    if(object[property]===3)
        console.log(`${property}: ${object[property]}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you want to use for and if at same time.

You should try this:

```
const object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

for (const property in object) {
    if(object[property]==3){
        console.log(`${property}: ${object[property]}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: While true, how is this different from the earlier answers? (Except for not being strict in the `==`.)

Answer (score -1):

for loop needs implementation of if condition bud, try this :

```js
const object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

for (const property in object) {
    if(object[property] == 3){
        console.log(`${property} : ${object[property]}`);
    }
}
```